# material UI create card in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the material ui here, I am trying to create a card that will be having a footer in the card and image.

[image]

So In this card, I am trying that image should be at the centre and also want to add some data in the footer but there is no footer for the card.

Can anyone help me with this

```
<Card className={css.root}>
  <CardContent>
    <CardMedia
      className={css.media}
      title="Contemplative Reptile"
      image={TestImage}
    />
    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2"></Typography>
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p"></Typography>
  </CardContent>
</Card>);
}
```

Comment: What's your design dear ganesh? you could write your own Footer component. and I offer you to wrap all Material UI components, even which of them without any changes.

Comment: @AmerllicA How do I add image at center at least that u can give me an hint

Comment: Dear bro, you can use `flex-box` CSS methods, or set `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` for the image or its wrapper to center it. but I guess your issue is using Material UI.

Answer (score 0):

Follow This pattern, put your **CardMedia** block outside of **CardContent** and use **component="img"** for align center to image in card

```
<Card className={css.root}>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            className={css.media}
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
            image={TestImage}
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2"></Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" ></Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
```